# How to migrate from wordpress.com to self-hosted wordpress

Tags: migration

I'm trying to migrate from wordpress.com to self-hosted wordpress. These are some of the things I've done, but I'm not quite able to migrate successfully.

- Changed my Godaddy account DNS to wordpress
- Through Godaddy Web hosting connection, I installed wordpress application
- From wordpress.com I performed domain mapping

***The site is allenkim.me and it currently works. From here, I decided I want to change it to self-host wordpress and no longer use wordpress.com

- I downloaded wordpress
- Followed the 5 min instruction
- Uploaded wordpress files on my web server

PROBLEM
when I try to visit allenkim.me/wp-admin/install.php in a web browser, it doesn't open.

I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** Edit **

Did you check your folder structure ?

did you rename the wordpress folder ?

have nested folders ?

** end edit **
@ allan z - that will not (always) work for an existing site , due to a multitude of reasons .

the best way is to either follow these instructions here :
[Moving wordpress to another server](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server)

or , do it manually , like I usually do , which is :

1. FTP ALL your files to the new server. (ALL means ALL, as is - including images, plugins, theme)
2. Update wp-config with new data. (install folder, DB...)
3. manually execute those SQL sentences :

   /**
   To update WordPress options with the new blog location:
   **/

   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

   /**
   fix URLs of the WordPress posts and pages:
   **/

   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');

   /**
   fix all internal links to own blog in all WordPress posts and pages:
   **/

   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');

Answer (score 4):

You did not need to perform URL mapping or anything near as complicated.

From your Dashboard (wp-admin), go to Tools -> Export, select "All content", and then hit "Download Export File". You'll get a massive XML file at the end. Next, go to your new site, get a clean install of Wordpress, and select Tools -> Import. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Well the problem is the new site is the old site. I'm just trying to move away from wordpress.com to self-host wordpress with the same domain and same web hosting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean not open ? what is the error ? 404 ? parse ? You should check your folder structure and files to see that they exist on the server - and with the path that you type as URL ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem allen is that your DNS is configured to Wordpress if I'm not confused.
You should delegate the DNS of your domain to your hosting IPs

I'm not familiar with godaddy but it should not be complicated

Answer (score 0):

If you import from local or http URL, its not import because wordpress.com only allow to https url for **media export** and import to your WordPress.