# How to use get_page_by_title() with qTranslate?

Tags: themes, multi-language, plugin-qtranslate, pages

Any idea how I can use the WP function `get_page_by_title()` with qTranslate installed?

for example:

```
$page_contact = get_page_by_title( '_e("[:en]contact");' ,'page' );
$page_contact_ID = $page_contact->ID; echo '~~~~'.$page_contact_ID;
```

The only way I can get a match is by including the whole string with all the languages - and there is no way that's going to work once people start editing the pages...

Comment: Can you describe what is your overall goal ? do you want to create a menu by language ? to create a list of posts ?

Comment: Hi - I simply want to use the WP function as it was designed - so that I can get post data based on finding a match to a post name - perhaps a regex to remove the non-default languages and all the qtranslate comments might work?

Comment: Again, I ask what is your FINAL goal, can you give a concrete example ? I am not asking about the WordPress function abilities . I just want to understand what is that you want to achieve in lame-mans-terms.

Comment: Hi - My aim is to make a menu using wp_list_pages - I want to exclude certain pages by page name - not page ID - as I will migrate the site from my localhost to at least one other server the ID will change - hence making it in theory easier to do this by page name - until I realised that qtransalte would interfere with this simple idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now that you know your final goal I can try to answer :

first , A little background for other people who will read this and might wonder why this question exists (because it can help also in other cases )

the function get_page_by_title() does exactly what the name  say . But qTarnslate , as well as other plugins , actually CHANGE the title in the DB .

The answer to such problems is using another less-known (but not less powerful) function called `get_page_by_path();`

why does this help ? Because the Path of the page will not be changed .
Usually it will be used like this :

```
get_page_by_path('parent-page/sub-page');
```

But a much more cool thing is that the "path" parameter can be the SLUG , which is NOT changed by qTranslate .

so for the direct answer , please try this :

```
$page = get_page_by_path('your-slug-of-page-to-exclude');
wp_list_pages('exclude='.$page->ID.'&title_li=');
```

that being said, and as a side note - there is no reason for you to lose the ID of pages when migration, if you simply export your DB and import to the new server , like described in the [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) or [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36133/how-to-migrate-from-wordpress-com-to-self-hosted-wordpress/36146#36146).